# How to change prefix of signature in Javascript?

Tags: solidity, signature, ecrecover

Is it possible to change the signature prefix, which by default:

`"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32"`

Can I change it to another `prefix`?

I need to get a signature in solidity in this way:

```
bytes32 signature = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix, hash));
```